# How to use notifyDataSetChanged() on a ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This must be a simple question, as I am new to Android.

I have a implementation of a ListAdapter but need to update the list when changes are made to the objects list that runs it. It is suggested in various posts to use notifyDataSetChanged(). However naturally I get the error 'cannot find method':

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_list_activity);        
((ListAdapter) lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In the onCreate() of the Activity I added it to the ListView:

```
lv.setAdapter(new MenuListAdapter(this, objects));
```

As the ListAdapter is only an interface. The method however is included in the ArrayAdaptor. 
So what should I use, what is the best way? I basically just have a List with objects to be used to populate the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adapters inheritance tree, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is defined in `BaseAdapter`. Assuming your `MenuListAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter` directly or indirectly, cast the result of `getAdapter()` to `BaseAdapter` to invoke the method.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do following

```
MenuListAdapter menuListAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, objects)
lv.setAdapter(menuListAdapter);
```

Now just call following anywhere.

```
menuListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As @laalto mentioned you must be extending right Adapter in your custom adapter class. Either BaseAdapter directly or any of the adapters that expend Base Adapter like ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score -1):

While creating the adapter store it into a local variable and then use that variable.

```
MenuListAdapter adapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, objects)
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

// You need to update the objects list, so that adapter can get the recent update
objects.add(newItem);

// Then notify the adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```